# Sublime Text - XPath Plugin shortcut

Tags: xpath, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have installed [Sublime Text - XPath Plugin](https://github.com/rosshadden/sublime-xpath), but I can not find a shortcut or button to start XPath search in Sublime. Specifically "enter xpath" row.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Command Palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`), and select `XPath: Query document`. This will open the "Enter xpath" input panel.

The XPath Plugin has no key bindings set by default. The [Example.sublime-keymap](https://github.com/rosshadden/sublime-xpath/blob/master/Example.sublime-keymap) file shows examples of what you might want to set.

The bottom example in the [Example.sublime-keymap](https://github.com/rosshadden/sublime-xpath/blob/master/Example.sublime-keymap) file, which is labelled "Show the XPath query input box", is the key binding that shows the "Enter xpath" input panel, the keys it uses are `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Super+q` would be so difficult to press that clearly the author intends users to change them. Have a look through what the example key bindings do and copy'n'paste the ones you want into your user keys file changing the keys they use to the keys that you would prefer.

For example you might want to add the binding below to your user keys to show the "Enter xpath" prompt with the `Ctrl+Shift+X` keys:

Note: Pay attention to helpful lines like this one from the example below: `"prefill_query": "//text()", // an XPath query to put into the input box by default - can omit and use "prefill_path_at_cursor": true instead to use the path of the node under the first cursor`. You might want to add 2 different key bindings to show the "Enter xpath" prompt; one to use `"prefill_query": "//text(),"` and the other to use `"prefill_path_at_cursor": true,`.

```
// Show the XPath query input box
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+x"],
    "command": "query_xpath",
    "args": {
        "prefill_query": "//text()", // an XPath query to put into the input box by default - can omit and use "prefill_path_at_cursor": true instead to use the path of the node under the first cursor
        "live_mode": true, // as per settings
        "normalize_whitespace_in_preview": false, // as per settings
        "intelligent_auto_complete": true, // as per settings
        "goto_element": "names", // same options available as for goto_relative
        "goto_attribute": "value", // options are name, value, entire
        "max_results_to_show": 1000 // as per settings
    }
},
```

Comment: I opened Command Palette (CP) and even if I have xpath plugin installed (I verified it by opening CP and found it in "Package Control: List Packages") there is no other option than "Set Syntax: Xpath 1.0" in CP.

Comment: you may need to change syntax to xml to make it work